# Why is git clone user@server working when git clone ssh://user@server doesn't?

Tags: git, ssh

I am new to git.  I have created a bare repository on a server on which I have SSH access.  If I try to clone it onto my workstation, I get two different results:

```
% git clone ssh://me@example.com:git/foo.git

Cloning into 'foo'...
ssh: example.com:git: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But if I remove the `ssh://`, it works fine:

```
% git clone me@example.com:git/foo.git
```

According to the Pro Git book these should be identical.

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The first command `git clone ssh://`, follows the standard [`SSH URI syntax`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/ssh) and hence you need to give absolute paths.

  Try this for instance (assuming the home directory for the user `me` is located at `/home/me`):

  ```
  git clone ssh://me@example.com/home/me/git/foo.git
  ```

  And I'm guessing this should also work:

  ```
  git clone ssh://me@example.com/~/git/foo.git
  ```
- The second syntax: `git clone me@example.com:git/foo.git` allows using relative paths from the user's home directory.